# Express Checkout with Paypal's PHP API cannot checkout without account

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I'm trying to test "Pay Without a Paypal Account" using a SetExpressCheckout call from Paypal's PHP api, but the Paypal page I'm directed to only has the options to pay with an account or create an account - **there is no option to pay without an account**.

I've configured the sandbox seller account I'm testing with to not require users to have accounts using the instructions here: https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Merchant-services-Archive/Paypal-account-optional/td-p/233270

Here's a printout of the setECReq object just before I call the $paypalService->SetExpressCheckout() method:

```
    PayPal\PayPalAPI\SetExpressCheckoutReq Object
(
    [SetExpressCheckoutRequest] => PayPal\PayPalAPI\SetExpressCheckoutRequestType Object
        (
            [SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails] => PayPal\EBLBaseComponents\SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType Object
                (
                    [OrderTotal] => 
                    [ReturnURL] => (stack overflow won't let me post links)/dg/cart/checkout/paypal/express/review
                    [CancelURL] => (stack overflow won't let me post links)/dg/cart/checkout/paypal/express/cancel
                    [TrackingImageURL] => 
                    [giropaySuccessURL] => 
                    [giropayCancelURL] => 
                    [BanktxnPendingURL] => 
                    [Token] => 
                    [MaxAmount] => 
                    [OrderDescription] => 
                    [Custom] => 
                    [InvoiceID] => 
                    [ReqConfirmShipping] => 0
                    [ReqBillingAddress] => 
                    [BillingAddress] => 
                    [NoShipping] => 0
                    [AddressOverride] => 0
                    [LocaleCode] => 
                    [PageStyle] => 
                    [cppheaderimage] => 
                    [cppheaderbordercolor] => 000000
                    [cppheaderbackcolor] => 000000
                    [cpppayflowcolor] => 00FF00
                    [cppcartbordercolor] => EEEEEE
                    [cpplogoimage] => (stack overflow won't let me post links)/dg/assets/img/paypal_logo2.gif
                    [Address] => 
                    [PaymentAction] => 
                    [SolutionType] => 
                    [LandingPage] => 
                    [BuyerEmail] => 
                    [ChannelType] => 
                    [BillingAgreementDetails] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => PayPal\EBLBaseComponents\BillingAgreementDetailsType Object
                                (
                                    [BillingType] => MerchantInitiatedBillingSingleAgreement
                                    [BillingAgreementDescription] => The customer pays for the products, and buyer sends them.
                                    [PaymentType] => 
                                    [BillingAgreementCustom] => 
                                )

                        )

                    [PromoCodes] => 
                    [PayPalCheckOutBtnType] => 
                    [ProductCategory] => 
                    [ShippingMethod] => 
                    [ProfileAddressChangeDate] => 
                    [AllowNote] => 1
                    [FundingSourceDetails] => 
                    [BrandName] => Dusty Gamble | Glass Art
                    [CallbackURL] => 
                    [EnhancedCheckoutData] => 
                    [OtherPaymentMethods] => 
                    [BuyerDetails] => 
                    [PaymentDetails] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => PayPal\EBLBaseComponents\PaymentDetailsType Object
                                (
                                    [OrderTotal] => PayPal\CoreComponentTypes\BasicAmountType Object
                                        (
                                            [currencyID] => USD
                                            [value] => 45.00
                                        )

                                    [ItemTotal] => PayPal\CoreComponentTypes\BasicAmountType Object
                                        (
                                            [currencyID] => USD
                                            [value] => 42.00
                                        )

                                    [ShippingTotal] => PayPal\CoreComponentTypes\BasicAmountType Object
                                        (
                                            [currencyID] => USD
                                            [value] => 3.00
                                        )

                                    [HandlingTotal] => PayPal\CoreComponentTypes\BasicAmountType Object
                                        (
                                            [currencyID] => USD
                                            [value] => 0.00
                                        )

                                    [TaxTotal] => 
                                    [OrderDescription] => 
                                    [Custom] => 
                                    [InvoiceID] => 
                                    [ButtonSource] => PayPal_SDK
                                    [NotifyURL] => 
                                    [ShipToAddress] => 
                                    [MultiShipping] => 
                                    [FulfillmentReferenceNumber] => 
                                    [FulfillmentAddress] => 
                                    [PaymentCategoryType] => 
                                    [ShippingMethod] => 
                                    [ProfileAddressChangeDate] => 
                                    [PaymentDetailsItem] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => PayPal\EBLBaseComponents\PaymentDetailsItemType Object
                                                (
                                                    [Name] => Object #883 - Synapse
                                                    [Number] => 
                                                    [Quantity] => 1
                                                    [Tax] => 
                                                    [Amount] => PayPal\CoreComponentTypes\BasicAmountType Object
                                                        (
                                                            [currencyID] => USD
                                                            [value] => 42.00
                                                        )

                                                    [EbayItemPaymentDetailsItem] => 
                                                    [PromoCode] => 
                                                    [ProductCategory] => 
                                                    [Description] => 
                                                    [ItemWeight] => 
                                                    [ItemLength] => 
                                                    [ItemWidth] => 
                                                    [ItemHeight] => 
                                                    [ItemURL] => 
                                                    [EnhancedItemData] => 
                                                    [ItemCategory] => Physical
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [InsuranceTotal] => PayPal\CoreComponentTypes\BasicAmountType Object
                                        (
                                            [currencyID] => USD
                                            [value] => 0.00
                                        )

                                    [ShippingDiscount] => 
                                    [InsuranceOptionOffered] => 
                                    [AllowedPaymentMethod] => 
                                    [EnhancedPaymentData] => 
                                    [SellerDetails] => 
                                    [NoteText] => 
                                    [TransactionId] => 
                                    [PaymentAction] => Sale
                                    [PaymentRequestID] => 
                                    [OrderURL] => 
                                    [SoftDescriptor] => 
                                    [BranchLevel] => 
                                    [OfferDetails] => 
                                    [Recurring] => 
                                    [PaymentReason] => 
                                )

                        )

                    [FlatRateShippingOptions] => 
                    [CallbackTimeout] => 
                    [CallbackVersion] => 
                    [CustomerServiceNumber] => 
                    [GiftMessageEnable] => 
                    [GiftReceiptEnable] => 
                    [GiftWrapEnable] => 
                    [GiftWrapName] => 
                    [GiftWrapAmount] => 
                    [BuyerEmailOptInEnable] => 
                    [SurveyEnable] => 
                    [SurveyQuestion] => 
                    [SurveyChoice] => 
                    [TotalType] => 
                    [NoteToBuyer] => 
                    [Incentives] => 
                    [ReqInstrumentDetails] => 
                    [ExternalRememberMeOptInDetails] => 
                    [FlowControlDetails] => 
                    [DisplayControlDetails] => 
                    [ExternalPartnerTrackingDetails] => 
                    [CoupledBuckets] => 
                )

            [DetailLevel] => 
            [ErrorLanguage] => 
            [Version] => 
        )

)
```

Comment: I found the answer by reading someone else's code:

    $setECReqDetails->SolutionType = 'Sole';

Comment: You would need SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole as well as LANDINGPAGE=Billing, however, I think with a billing agreement added it's still going to require a PayPal account.